# How do I force an html5 embedded video to finish playing?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video

Some background: this is actually a web object in an Articulate Presenter '13 course, loaded into an instance of Mooodle LMS.

The 'web object' is just an html file I wrote, the relevant part of which is written like so:

```html
<video width="720" height="406" controls src="http://download.atsmedia.com/LMS/PGE/COUB-Sale.mp4" type="video/mp4">
<p>If you are reading this, it is because your browser does not support the HTML5 video element.</p>
</video>
```

I've been avoiding javascript as I want to keep everything as cross-platform & cross-browser friendly as possible. So I'm looking for the simplest solution. If anyone has additional info relating to Articulate Presenter '13 (or even Moodle), I'm all ears - the goal there is to force the video to finish before the learner can advance to the next slide.

Answer (score 0):

> the goal there is to force the video to finish before the learner can advance to the next slide.

Not using JavaScript in a case like this is like expecting a pizza delivered without ordering one (and JavaScript is really not a cross-platform issue).

The only way the video element can tell the browser environment that it has finished (excluding the visuals/UI) is to broadcast the event for `ended`. To pick up this event you need JavaScript.

On an ended event you can enable a next button or something of that sort:

## Example

The video below will skip to 8:04 minutes (in browsers that support media fragments - so you don't need to skip to the end, not a requirement) and when the video ends the button above it named NEXT will be enabled -

```js
document.querySelector("video").addEventListener("ended", function() {
  // enable NEXT button when video finished:
  document.querySelector("button").disabled = false;
})
```

```css
body {background:#999}
button:disabled {color:#ccc}
```

```html
<button disabled=true>NEXT</button><br>
<video autoplay width="720" height="406" controls src="http://download.atsmedia.com/LMS/PGE/COUB-Sale.mp4#t=484" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. This is great information for me.